# What does readyState ==1 means?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-web-api2, dynamics-crm

I am using this below function to fetch the product number for a particular `productid`.

```js
function GetQuickCode(){

    var material = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("one_materialid").getValue();
    var id = material[0].id;
    id=id.replace("{","").replace("}","");

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/products("+id+")?$select=productnumber", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                var productnumber = result["productnumber"];
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("one_quickcode").setValue(productnumber.Value);
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

this function is returning `readyState==1` which is why I am unable to find the value of product number. Also the response value does not contain anything. Can anyone tell me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: Could you help me find out why the readyState is 1. I have checked my httprequest. it seems to be ok

Comment: I don't even see where inside your function you check when `readyState == 1`...

Comment: i get this value during debug mode. the req.open statement does not return the expected url. it says undefined

Comment: Try using Fiddler to profile the request and response

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your code in a few steps to find the problem.

First replace this line of code

```js
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/products("+id+")?$select=productnumber", true);
```

by

```js
var url= Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/products("+id+")?$select=productnumber";    
console.log(url);
req.open("GET", url, true);
```

1. Does URL look correct?
2. Does it return correct result if you open directly in your browser?

If it works, you can continue further. If not, you need to fix the URL. You can start by removing parts from the end of the URL. Also, what is your CRM version? Is it 8.2 (Dynamics 365)?

Second, by using debug mode, inspect object `this`, especially attributes `response` and `responseText`, whether they contains some message.

Third, in F12 tool inspect the request and response. The tab is called Net or Network depending on browser. There can be many items. Clear the list before running your code. Look there what happened, what is returned for your request.